# how do I predict a categorical class for given string (unseen data) on trained tensor flow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, categorical-data, multiclass-classification

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features,
                embedding_dims,
                input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Conv1D(filters,
             kernel_size,
             padding='valid',
             activation='relu',
             strides=1))

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=32,
      epochs=50,
      validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

model trained succesfully!! but how do i predict class for a given string
how do I predict a categorical class for given string (unseen data) on this trained tensor flow model.

Comment: What have you tried ? From [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate/) you can try `predictions = model.predict(unseen_data_like_x_train)
`

Comment: I've trained csv file having text and multiple classes
I tried this                                                
 model.predict("that unseen data") this gives error

Comment: Could you share the complete error traceback and code snippet consisting of model.predict(). Thanks!